# Database design users-categories-pictures (cyclical relationship?!)

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, database-normalization

I have to design a simple database, but things are harder than they appear. It's very simple to fall in a cycle relationship.

- A user can choose one or more categories (e.g. animals, humans, landscape, nature, abstract etc.)
- The same category can be chosen by other users (n-n relationship between users and categories)
- Pictures can be assigned to one or more categories so a category can have one or more pictures (n-n relationship between pictures and categories)
- Now it's time to historicize viewed pictures so I think there's another relation between pictures and users, which is also n-n, because a user could view one or more pictures and the same picture could be viewed by n users

Users <---> categories <---> pictures

Users <---> pictures

In my opinion that design has a cycle relationship, could you help me solve this situation? Have you an idea?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with 'historicize'?

Comment: What you you think a "cycle relationship" is? Why do you think it is a problem? Where is the one here?

Comment: @GustvandeWal Historicize as "keep informations over time"

Comment: @philipxy the problem is that : Users <---> categories <---> pictures <---> Users | where "<---->" stays for n-n

Comment: The pictures in the categories chosen by a user is not the same thing as the pictures viewed by a user.  Is there any need for consistency between these two relationships?  If not, I see no problem.  Multiple relationships between two concepts are a natural and normal part of modeling.

Comment: That image adds nothing.

Comment: @philipxy what do you mean? What i have to explain?

Comment: You say that you have the "opinion" that there is a "cycle" "problem". *Why?* (There isn't.) Please give a reference to the style of ER diagram and/or schema definition that you are using. (Your diagram/schema is incomplete.) Please give a reference to a textbook or documentation that explains how *the kind of cycle in your diagram/schema* is a problem. (It isn't.) If you can't then you don't have an opinion or a problem; you merely heard a vague rumour about some sort of problem with some sort of thing whose name reminds you of some sort of thing in some sort of diagram/schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem here.

If all of the relationships were in use for a query, it would probably be of the type "Show me the pictures in this user's categories that they have not yet viewed", which seems like a reasonable business case.

So you'd have a query that joins users to categories to picture, and checks for non-existence of a record in the "user_picutres_viewed" table for that picture and user.

Not a problem.